# How to Handle special characters in xml payload using c# in web api

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

I am using the following block of code to read XML data

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostPurchaseOrder(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {          
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();          
        document.Load(request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);          
    }
```

But Facing issue when having special characters like &,$,#  in XML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.008/cXML.dtd">; 
<cXML timestamp="2017-04-06T05:44:31-04:00" version="1.2.0025"
       payloadID="ddae78e3-20b0-4f9d-91b8-7ca854f27568" xml:lang="en-US"> 
 <Header> <From> <Credential domain="NetworkId"> 
  <Identity>FakeIdentity & &</Identity> 
  </Credential> </From> 
 </cXML>
```

Comment: Please be a *lot* more specific. "But facing issue" doesn't tell us anything about what the input looks like or what problems you're facing. Please provide a [mcve]. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, apart from anything else - you're parsing it as XML, then getting it as a string again... why?

Comment: i am trying to parse XML data posted on fiddler or postman but                    document.Load(request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result); is not working when xml having special characters

Comment: Again, "is not working" is incredibly vague. Do you get an exception? Something else? What is the input data?

Comment: @JonSkeet : can using HtmlDecode work for the result      as document.Load(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result));

Comment: @AbdulKhan: If the data is meant to be XML, that would be a bad idea.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.008/cXML.dtd">
<cXML timestamp="2017-04-06T05:44:31-04:00" version="1.2.0025" payloadID="ddae78e3-20b0-4f9d-91b8-7ca854f27568" xml:lang="en-US">
   <Header>
      <From>
         <Credential domain="NetworkId">
            <Identity>FakeIdentity & &</Identity>
         </Credential>
      </From>     
</cXML>

Comment: Getting 500 status code because having '&'  in Identity node

Comment: This is *not XML* but rather text with angle braces... Valid XML does not have `&` unencoded. (BTW, make sure to [edit] post with your information)